# Pytest IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

Currently I'm trying to configure my django rest API with pytest. When I tried to use models with `@pytest.mark.django_db` I get an error mentioning that `tuple index out of range` even though I do not refer any tuples in the test case. But everything works fine when I do not do any database queries or not use `@pytest.mark.django_db`

```py
import pytest
from report_tenant.models import VisualModelTableColumn


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_visual_model_table_column_table():
    col = Model.objects.create(key_1=1, key_2=1, key_5=1, key_3=1, key_4=1)
    assert True == True
```

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I named my *conftest* as *confest*. Renaming it got my job done.

**Conclusion: If someone is having any issue with the DB connectivity when using pytest, just checking the conftest would most probably get you job done.**